# Getting "The term 'pwsh.exe' is not recognized" in Azure DevOps hosted pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to run a YAML based pipeline (ubunutu-latest) in one of my DevOps organisations. One of the steps is defined as follows:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Say hello'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Hello"
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    pwsh: true
```

This works in all my other orgs and matches the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines). When I execute the pipeline the task above results in the following error:

```
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Formatted command: . 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\1\ci\drop\pipeline-scripts\check-health.ps1'
##[error]The term 'pwsh.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

As far as I know this task "PowerShell@2" does not need further settings in the org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls, check your vmimage reference. This line says you are using Windows VM (not ubuntu-latest):

> Formatted command: .
> 'C:\azagent\A1_work\1\ci\drop\pipeline-scripts\check-health.ps1'

This is how it looks like in ubuntu:

```
Starting: PowerShell Script
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/08e68401-b820-42a0-8b7f-111189d71fca.ps1'
Hello World
Finishing: PowerShell Script
```